# searching for a word in all triggers in a schema - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I'm having problems running my application - Oracle is raising an

```
ORA-04092: cannot COMMIT in a trigger issue.
```

Now I am trying to find the trigger which contains commit statement. Is it possible to find the trigger which has the commit statement in all `dba_triggers'?

```
select * from dba_triggers statement
```

gives me all dba triggers. Now I have to search these triggers with the word `commit`.

Comment: You can export your triggers as PL/SQL and just search as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get the full error stack, you should be able to see what line of what trigger is throwing the error.  That's the most efficient approach.  For example, if you create a trigger that commits and run an INSERT, the stack trace will show you what line of what trigger caused the error.

```
SQL> create table t (
  2    col1 number
  3  );

Table created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create trigger trg_t
  2    before insert on t
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    commit;
  6* end;
SQL> /

Trigger created.

SQL> begin
  2    insert into t values( 1 );
  3  end;
  4  /
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04092: cannot COMMIT in a trigger
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_T", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_T'
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

You can search the source for all triggers looking for a particular string.  Something like this will look for the literal "COMMIT" in any trigger in whatever schemas you specify.

```
SELECT name, text, line
  FROM dba_source
 WHERE owner IN (<<schemas you want to search>>)
   AND upper(text) like '%COMMIT%';
```

On the other hand, there is a strong probability that the trigger that is failing is calling a stored procedure and it is the stored procedure that is committing.  So searching the source of your triggers may not be beneficial.

You could potentially mitigate that by doing a recursive query on `DBA_DEPENDENCIES` (or `ALL_DEPENDENCIES` or `USER_DEPENDENCIES` depending on your privilege level and the scope of what you want to search for) to find all of the procedures that are potentially called from any trigger and to search the source of all of those procedures from `DBA_SOURCE`.  But that's going to be much more complex than simply examining the full error stack.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Justin Cave..if possible could you provide the query for the second approach ..sorry..i dont have full db knowledge as i am a java developer..pls

Comment: @Satya - It would take me a bit to put together and test the second query.  Are you sure that you can't get the full error stack instead?  The full error stack is going to immediately pinpoint the problem-- even the second query is likely to involve quite a bit of manual effort analyzing the results.

Comment: Thanks Justin..This is the error stacktrace i got.Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-04092: cannot COMMIT in a trigger
ORA-06512: at line 60
 but it doesnt contain the procedure or trigger(which causing this problem) details..as i am trying to connect this db from java application. ..thank you so much for your help justin.

Comment: @Satya - I posted an example of the stack trace that you get.  Can you run whatever procedure is failing from SQL*Plus to get the full stack trace?